# How to get rid of unwanted files references with Git

Tags: git

I accidentally scaffolded a boilerplate project inside a project's working tree with a Git repository (I was inside a project folder, created a folder, entered it and typed `yo gulp-webapp`).

It happens, right?

So first I reverted the overwritten files with `git checkout HEAD -- <filename>`.

After that, by typing `git status` some unwanted files were showing in "Untracked files".

I deleted them (via Sublime Text) and then they showed up in "Changes not staged for commit". Why? Weren't they untracked, meaning they were never added to the repository?

Then I deleted them using `git -rm -rf`. Now they show up in Staging area. What's happening.

How do I make Git forget about them?

Answer (score 5):

```
git clean -xdf
```

This will remove untracked files, directories (-d) and files ignored by .gitignore (-x).

Be careful not to delete files by accident, this will clean anything not tracked.

You can add the `--dry-run` parameter to see what would be removed.

Comment: That deleted the physical files listed in .gitignore and the unwanted files I mentioned were still showing up on `git status`. I didn't want to delete any files from the working tree, just needed that Git stopped referencing some  unwanted files that were created by mistake.

Comment: If `git status` shows the current index is different than the HEAD commit it's another issue. `git reset --hard` should fix it.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean, but I believe I should have used `git clean -df` instead of deleting them via Sublime Text (or Finder, or with `rm`). Anyway, I still don't understand why, after deleting them via Sublime, they showed up as deleted in "Changes not staged for commit" since they were never added.

Answer (score 0):

After you did `git rm`, the files appeared in the staging area because they are to be deleted in the repository, i.e. it is correct that they are there. Simply commit the deletions and you should be good to go.

Comment: If they were to be deleted in the repository, it means that they were added to the repository at some point, correct? How they were added? I've never added them!

Comment: Yes, they would have had to have been added at some point. If you did not add them, then I'm not sure what's going on. The very puzzling bit is where they were untracked, you deleted them, and then they were all of a sudden tracked. What do you see when you do a log of one of the files, i.e. `git log file.txt`?

Comment: yes, very puzzling indeed! `git log` for one of those files returns me "fatal: ambiguous argument 'test/karma.conf.js': unknown revision or path not in the working tree."